# n dimensional torus

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm here trying to recognize an (n-1)-dimensional manifold in $R^n$  whose structure can be sumarized as Interval times union of two codimension 2 spheres that meet a common cod-2 sphere at one end of the interval, and another common cod-2 sphere at the other end. My guess is it is a torus.

My motivation is, let's think of a standard 2-torus in $R^3$ horizontally placed. By fixing descendant values for z, we get (from top to bottom) a circle (codimension two sphere), union of two circles (likewise) until it hits the lower critical value again in one sphere.

Having this in mind, my guess is my manifold is a torus since it has that exact same structure but I'm not 100% certain...

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you take the union of two disjoint circles in $\Bbb R^3$ and take the product with a closed interval, you get the union of two cylinders. Are there some identifications going on (there are in your torus description)?

Comment: In this setting, you would get a torus since the borders of the cylinders would be coincident. In fact, the interval is closed; and while the variable moves within it from one end to the other, we start with one single sphere, then we get disjoint spheres that reach one common sphere again at the other end of the interval. It is exactly like the situation described in $R^3$ but in higher dimension. All changes are smooth too.

Comment: Your description doesn't say the cylinders are connected at the endpoints. That's why I asked if you're making some identifications. The original description said *product*.

Comment: Yes, I recognize it is not sufficiently clearly stated in the original post. Sorry :)

Comment: It's been edited now for better understanding. I can't help also noticing that it said "that exact same structure" from the beginning :)

Comment: So you take two copies of $S^m\times[0,1]$, and glue their ends together? That's just $S^m\times S^1$.

Comment: Well, now that you mention it, yes, that's what it is. I was trying to get some further type of classification but this simple and obvious fact will be useful for my purpose (I can't see how I didn't see it lol, I was so much expecting it were a torus that I lost track). As a side comment, since $m>1$ it can never be a torus. Thank you all guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manifold is $S^{n-2}_r \times S^1$ also known as *Dupin cyclide*